# Cassandra 2.0 - Single node setup timing out on write - replication/consistency?

Tags: java, ubuntu, cassandra, bigdata, datastax

I am trying to benchmark cassandra (2.0.9) in a very basic setup (single node), however using the datastax driver (2.0.4) I am getting a WriteTimeoutException very early into my batch insert. I'm using a 4-core machine with 14GB ram, jvm oracle 8u11. Does anyone have any ideas why my writes are failing?

Below is my logging output.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2014-08-08 17:33:46 INFO ***.***.SimpleClient connect Connected to cluster: Test Cluster

2014-08-08 17:33:46 INFO ***.***.SimpleClient connect Connected to cluster: Test Cluster
Datacenter: datacenter1; Host: /<ip address>; Rack: rack1

2014-08-08 17:33:49 INFO ***.***.SimpleClient loadData i: 0
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:54)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:172)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
    at ***.***.SimpleClient.loadData(SimpleClient.java:97)
    at ***.***.App.cassandraMapInsert(App.java:371)
    at ***.***.App.main(App.java:354)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:54)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:93)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:235)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.onSet(RequestHandler.java:379)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:584)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:777)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:71)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:777)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:327)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:305)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:207)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:553)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:343)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:274)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:194)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (1 replica were required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:54)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:34)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:182)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:67)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you show `iostat -xdm 1` output when this issue happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your timeout in conf/cassandra.yaml file.

write_request_timeout_in_ms